# QLThumbnailGenerator USDZ Angle of render

Tags: swift, quicksort, usdz

I'm using QLThumbnailGenerator to render thumbnails of USDZ files,

I'm curious as to what decides the roll/pitch/yaw angles of the rendered image?

The position of the render is maybe 30 degrees (up Z), and 30 degrees (around Y), looking down into the center (0,0,0).

I could understand if the image was rendered through the Z-Plane, but it isn't

Is there any way of know why it does this, or is there a way to control this?

```
 func generate(url: URL, target: URL) {
    let request = QLThumbnailGenerator.Request(fileAt: url, size: .init(width: 300, height: 300), scale: NSScreen.main!.backingScaleFactor, representationTypes: .all)
    
    let gen = QLThumbnailGenerator.shared
    gen.generateBestRepresentation(for: request) { (rep, err) in
        
        let saved = rep?.nsImage.pngWrite(to: target)
        
    }
}
```